# svg file in html and i want to covert the javascript formate

Tags: javascript, svg

i have one svg file in html and i want to get path front that file like

```
data:[-23.978,2.474,0,-18.691,2.474,0,-16.108,2.595,0,-14.207,2.866,0,-12.443,3.292,0,-11.003,3.793,0,-9.653,4.413,0,-8.741,4.929,0,-7.869,5.506,0,-6.341,6.686,0,-5.837]
```

Like this above format please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need like this?

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("polygon")[0].getAttribute("points"); 


var x = document.getElementsByTagName("path")[0].getAttribute("d"); 
var obj = {};
obj['data'] = x.split(' ');
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>

  <svg widht:"100" height:"100">
<path d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks rejs give me your answer. but not of this format i want to svg file is create on the JavaScript data:[-23.978,2.474,0,-18.691,2.474,0,-16.108,2.595,0,-14.207] like this format